# Incremental transition-delay for appended items

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I have a page using infinite-scroll.js, which loads 8 `.product` div on initial load (and adds a `.loaded` class), and then a further 8 `.product` div upon clicking a button to run infinite-scroll (which adds an `.appended` class to each).

I am trying to add incremental `transition-delay` to each `.product` (first 100ms, second 200ms, third 300ms and so on), but to only take effect as and when they are added to the DOM. The code I'm currently using adds a `transition-delay` to all `.product` div's using `:nth-child()`, which means that when appending the additional items, they have a long `transition-delay`. For example, the first appended item currently uses i.e `:nth:child(9)` (so has a long delay of 900ms), but I want the transition-delay loop to start over, i.e `:nth-child(1)` (100ms).

HTML

```
<div class="product loaded">Product 1</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 2</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 3</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 4</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 5</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 6</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 7</div>
<div class="product loaded">Product 8</div>

<!-- Appended upon running of infinite-scroll.js -->
<div class="product appended">Product 9</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 10</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 11</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 12</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 13</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 14</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 15</div>
<div class="product appended">Product 16</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.product {
    // Step fade
    @for $i from 1 to 50 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) { transition-delay: $i * 100ms; }
    }
}
```

**JQUERY (Adds class to appended items)**

```
// Add class to appended items to enable step fade
$grid.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function(event, response, path, items) {
     $(items).delay(10).queue(function() {
        $(this).addClass('appended');
     });
});
```

Comment: SASS has a modulo operator as well, as far as I know …

Comment: Hey @04FS, can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this,

```
.product {
    // Step fade
    @for $i from 0 to 49 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i+1}) { transition-delay: ($i % 8 + 1) * 100ms; }
    }
}
```

will get you a result looking like this,

```
.product:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.product:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.product:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.product:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 400ms;
}
.product:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 500ms;
}
.product:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}
.product:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 700ms;
}
.product:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: 800ms;
}
.product:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.product:nth-child(10) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
...
.product:nth-child(48) {
  transition-delay: 800ms;
}
.product:nth-child(49) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you @04FS. This is exactly what I was after. It would be useful if you could break down your answer to explain what is happening?

Comment: The modulo operator gives you the reminder of the integer division, and can be used to easily “clamp down” a growing counter to repeating intervals of 0 to X-1 (with X being second operand of the modulo operation.) Since we don’t want 0ms for the first item, I added 1 after the modulo operation, and “counter-corrected” for that by modifying the start value of the loop, and the output inside the nth-child (`#{$i+1}`)